# when does the main thread die?

Tags: java, multithreading

The question was to generate random numbers between 1 and 99 using a thread. However the problem here is I don't know where does the "main thread is stopping" coming from?
Doesn't the main thread die in the end?

This is the sample output:

```
Main thread stopping
Random no = 57
Random no = 47
Random no = 96
Random no = 25
Random no = 74
Random no = 15
Random no = 46
Random no = 90
Random no = 52
Random no = 97
Thread that generates random nos is stopping
```

Mythread class:

```
public class MyThread extends Thread {
    MyThread() {
        // default constructor
    }

    MyThread(String threadName) {
        super(threadName); // Initialize thread.
        start();
    }

    public void run() {
        // System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName());
        Random rand = new Random();
        int newValue;
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            newValue = rand.nextInt(99);// generates any vale between 1 to 99
            System.out.println("Random no = " + newValue);
        }
        System.out.println("Thread that generates random nos is stopping");

    }
}
```

Main class:

```
public class HW5ex2a {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        MyThread t = new MyThread();
        t.start();
        t.join();// wait for the thread t to die

        System.out.println("Main thread stopping");

    }
}
```

Comment: The main thread "dies" when the `main` method is exited, therefore: yes, of course.

Comment: but the sample output gives "main thread is stopping" in the beginning. thats confusing

Comment: As soon as the Thread completes it work, that is, completes execution of run() method, Mythread releases its lock.As Main Thread just has MyThread to complete its work, so as soon as MyThread completes its execution, Main Thread also dies.

Comment: Are you sure about this output?

Comment: thats what the question has asked. However I think its a typo because it doesnt make sense. If the main thread stops before MyThread then Mythread wont work right?

Comment: if the main thread exits first, then the process is destroyed along with all the threads.  That is not happening in your example.  If you want to see it happening that way, just remove the line t.join()

Answer (score 2):

You can't rely on the order that main thread and other threads write to System.out.
Your thread t executes fine, the main thread waits for it to finish and then the main thread exits, all as expected.  But this isn't reflected in the order that you see on System.out.

To directly answer your question - the main thread waits for the thread to finish, then it writes a message to System.out, then it dies. The only confusing thing is that, because you are writing to System.out from two different threads, you don't have any guarantees about the relative ordering.  Println's from the two different threads could show up interleaved in any way...it just happens to show up with the output from the main thread first.

As Alexis Leclerc points out - you get an unpredictable interleaving, the same as in this [java threads tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/interfere.html).

Comment: My sample output shows:
Random no = 80
Random no = 9
Random no = 60
Random no = 24
Random no = 24
Random no = 50
Random no = 57
Random no = 25
Random no = 97
Random no = 12
Thread that generates random nos is stopping
Main thread stopping

Which is expected but the question has the sample output as typed in the question above. I dont know how to fix that.

Comment: @Graham I'd suggest adding this [Thread Interference](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/interfere.html) reference to your answer, if you judge it appropriate. I found it quite useful to better understand that Thread order is unpredictable.

Comment: When I run the above code, it gives me the expected output with the expected order therefore I dont think the problem is with the order.

Answer (score 1):

### Memory Synchronization in a Multi-core System

Since both threads are being run on separate cores (most probably), the objects that the threads have access to are cached by each core (in L1 cache) for improved performance.

Whenever the state of the object is changed, all caches try to synchronize with value in RAM, which is not guarantied to occur immediately.

Some threads might be able to synchronize before other threads even if it violates **happens-before** relationship between them.

The reason behind this lies in the implementation of the [java memory model](http://vimeo.com/28763316).

---

The same thing is happening with `System.out` object here.

You can not guaranty the order in which the data is passed and flushed through it.

Therefore it is unpredictable. Calling

```
System.out.flush();
```

might improve the result, but it will not guaranty.

---

For more, refer to [Multiple threads using System.out.println in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9467759/multiple-threads-using-system-out-println-in-java)

Hope this helps.

Comment: System.out.println automatically calls System.out.flush

Answer (score 0):

The main thread exit on below situation :-

1. Normally when program execution complete .
2. If you are using `System.exit(1)`.
3. JVM crashes.

Hope it will help you.